# CSS - modify parent based on first child

Tags: css

Is there a way in CSS to modify the parent element, given the first child?

In my case, this would be to format a table cell differently if the first child is a link.

```
<td>Hello</td>
<td><a href="go.html">Go here!</a></td>

<style>
td { padding: 5px; } /* Normal cell */
?? { padding: 0px; } /* Cell with link as first child */
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can think of a different approach and do something like:

```
td { padding: 5px; } /* Normal cell */
td a { margin: -5px; } /* Cell with link as first child */
```

There are many other ways to do the similar, of course.

CSS4 should offer a `:has` pseudo class which would do exactly what you wanted, but we need to wait for it.

Comment: Both of these answer my question: short-term and long-term solution. I know there used to be :contains; I imagine :has will do the same. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. If your project is much more complex than the example here, then I'd suggest you set a class to all those td elements that have anchor inside and then simply do `td.hasAnchorClass {padding: 0}`, that would probably be the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Shomz. Looks like I got ahead of myself. Maybe less condescending tone next time.

Comment: No problem, @BJack. Sorry about the tone but believe me, my tone was much less cruel than the storm of downvotes that you'd probably get within minutes.