# SCSS: Modify child's property when parent adds a class

Tags: sass

Using SCSS I was wondering if there if any more elegant way (using the `&`) to modify a child based on the parent adding a certain class.

The only way I found is this one: [CSS - modify parent based on first child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747188/css-modify-parent-based-on-first-child)

This is what works (based on the answer above):

```
.parent {
  .child  {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
.parent.certain-class {
  .child  {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is something like that:

```
.parent {
  .child  {
    opacity: 0.5;

    collapsed& {
      opacity: 1.0;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in SCSS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way to do it in scss.
Using the & followed by a classname without space.
Check Example below.

```
.parent {
  .child  {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

&.certain-class {
  .child  {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }

}
```